# selecting vector path only from the current layer in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

does anyone know if it is possible to "shield" other layers from path selection?
for example lets say I have 3 layers with different vector shapes in each one that overlap eachother in some points. if I click on layer 3 I want to edit the vector in layer 3 only and i don't want photoshop to select and move to vectors from layers below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can better target vector paths by using the Paths Panel.

Unfortunately, in Photoshop "lock" doesn't actually mean lock in many cases. I've submitted a few feature requests asking for lock to disable object selections, but so far nothing has been implemented.